# How to operate Nikon D300 in Bulb mode with the ML-3 IR remote

Tags: remote, nikon-d300, bulb-mode

When I put my Nikon D300 on Bulb the shutter opens for as long as I press the shutter release button and it closes when I let go of the button. If I try that with the remote, there is no way to hold the button. It just opens and closes the shutter for a very short time.

Is it possible to have the shutter open at the first press of the button and then close the shutter at the second press of the button?

Comment: ML-3 or ML-L3? They're quite a bit different.

Comment: ML-3 as shown on [this picture](https://static.fotokonijnenberg.nl/product_images/large/18226.jpg). The remote does not have a Bulb setting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I know for sure... :)

The **ML-3** can do bulb mode. Set the camera to bulb and the remote to continuous (C) and as long as you hold the button (and maintain IR connection) the shutter should remain open. See this [Photography Life article](http://photographylife.com/reviews/nikon-ml-3-compact-modulite-remote) for some info.

For completeness, the **ML-L3** IR remote (the other I asked you about) can also do bulb on supported cameras. In that situation, the camera should be in manual mode, shutter speed set to "--" and then the shutter is tripped on first press and closed on second press.

Comment: Yes that works !